# divide the spaces evenly IF items fit within the device's screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a top section that contains codes : "**A**" "**B**" "**C**" "**D**" "**E**"

If I simply use these text, I could just use `Row` widget and wrap each widget with `Expanded`.

However, when I click in each of these letters, they expand to their corresponding value.

e.g. when **A** is clicked, it will change to **Anonymous**.

The top section will now become : "**Anonymous**" "**B**" "**C**" "**D**" "**E**"

If the screen isn't wide enough, it will cause `overflow error`.

What I want to happen is that if the device's screen is wide enough, it would fit all of the `Text` widget **evenly**. If not, it would scroll horizontally.

Comment: Can use wrap widget...however it will push the extra content to next line

Comment: Also listview.builder can be used with scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, which will keep the content scrolling horizontally without overflow.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

Using either `CustomMultiChildLayout` or write your own custom render object, would be the most efficient way to handle this situation.

A slightly sub-optimal but still very good method is to use `TextPainter` to figure out the width of each of the texts, and use `LayoutBuilder` to obtain the total available width, then do your own calculation to decide if they will fit or not, and then design your layout accordingly.